# Smallest $N$ for which we can guarantee the approximation error of an alternating series

Tags: calculus, summation

What is the smallest value $N$ for which we can guarantee that the approximation error of the alternating series

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{7/2}}$$

by the partial sum, $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{7/2}}$$ is at most  $10^{-2}$?

Comment: Hint : After the $n$th term how by how much does the value of series increase or decrease? Hint 2 : each term also gets smaller ( no surprise there if working with a converging series).

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums)?

Comment: "After the nth term how by how much does the value of series increase or decrease?" Do you mean where it converges?

Comment: I know that when n = 1 that s = -1 and when n = 2 s = -0.088 n = 3 s = -0.021 s= 4 n =-0.0078.... Wait now i see the answer is three because s = 4 is beyond the error range of 10^-2. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternating series
with terms that decrease in absolute value.
This means that the sum
is always bounded
by any two consecutive partial sums
and the error is less than
the last term used.

So, you know that if
$1/n^{7/2} < 10^{-2}$
then this $n$ will be certainly enough.
This means
$n^{7/2} > 100$
or
$n > 100^{2/7}
= 10^{4/7}
= 3.7...
$
so $n \ge 4$ will do.

To find the minimum $n$,
get the sums for smaller $n$
and get a more accurate estimate
by taking a larger $n$
and see which differs
by less than $.01$.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Comment: You could (and should) use the absolute value of the first term not used as an upper bound for the error.

Comment: David Mitra is right. My statement was careless, though correct.